# Do not trigger UITapGesture in subview

Tags: ios, swift, video

As you can see in the image below I have a video which covers almost the entire screen. I want the video to play/stop whenever one taps on it. The code works almost perfectly fine, the thing is the class in which I call the `defInteractions` function also contains the `booked` and `comments` subview which can also be found below. Consequently, the video also plays/stops when one taps these areas which I don't want.

The UITapGestureRecognizer triggering the function to play/pause the video:

```
//set interactions
func defInteractions (){

    //singletap
    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(singleTapDetected(_:)))
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    //singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    //controlsContainerView
    controlsContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
}

//define type
var player: AVPlayer?

//set playing to false
var isPlaying: Bool = false

func singleTapDetected(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    //play or pause
    if(!isPlaying){

        //play
        player?.play()
        isPlaying = true

    }
    else{

        //pause
        player?.pause()
        isPlaying = false

    }

}
```

Each subview looks basically like this:

```
//create controls container view
let comments: UIView = {

   //set properties of controls container view
   let commentrect = CGRect(x: viewWidth / 2, y: viewHeight - 110, width: viewWidth / 2, height: 50)
   let entireCommentView = UILabel(frame: commentrect)

   entireCommentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
   entireCommentView.backgroundColor = .white

   entireCommentView.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 20)

   entireCommentView.text = "3 comments"
   entireCommentView.textColor = .black
   entireCommentView.textAlignment = .center

   return entireCommentView

}()
```

In the `override` they are added as subviews. I tried setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to false in the individual subviews (e.g. comments: `entireCommentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`) which didn't work and don't know how to achieve my goal. Can someone help me? Can I exclude these subviews from my target in the `UITapGestureRecognizer` recognizer.

[[image: The video shall play/pause when the video (and only the video) is clicked].[1]]

EDIT (Result of first answer):[image: result of first answer]

Answer (score 0):

Modify the singleTapDetected to return if the tap is in any of the top or bottom UIViews.

```
func singleTapDetected(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let view = sender.view
    let loc = sender.location(in: controlsContainerView)
    if let subview = view?.hitTest(loc, with: nil) {
        if subview == entireCommentView || subview == bookedView {
            return
        }
    }

    //play or pause
    player?.rate != 0 && player?.error == nil ? player?.pause() : player?.play

}
```

Alternatively, you can have your `UIViewController` adopt the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol and call the below method for checking the view. Inside this method, check your view against touch.view and return the appropriate bool (Yes/No). Something like this:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        return !touch.view?.isDescendant(of: controlsContainerView)
    }
```

Comment: Where should I put the first function? If I put it outside my `override`, the `UITapGestureRecognizer` tells me there's no `singleTapDetected` function. If I put both of them in my `override`, it tells me I can't do that because `singleTapDetected` is a local function. And if I let both of them outside the `override`, it tells 'use of unresolved identifier 'entireCommentView'' because `entireCommentView` is added as subview in the `override`

Comment: What do you mean by inside and outside your `override` ? If you use the first option I suggested, the `singleTapDetected` method should be implemented inside the `UIViewController` which contains the `defInterfactions` method you declared to bind the tap gesture to your container.

Comment: I edited the error into my question. This is not inside a `UIViewController` class but in a `UIView` class... if I print `subview` I always get the same thing in the console independently from where I tap

Answer (score 0):

You should define the likes and booked variables as property of the UIView subclass itself, to make them visible to your `singleTapDetected(_:)` method